# BeautifulSoup with empty class name

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="table-wrap table-onerow">
       <table id="equityInfo" class="eq-series table-fullwidth w-100">
          <thead>
             <tr>
               <th>Series
               </th>
               <th>Symbol
               </th>
               <th>ISIN
               </th>
               <th>Status
               </th>
               <th>Date of Listing
               </th>
               <th>Industry
               </th>
               <th>Symbol P/E
               </th>
               <th>Sectoral Index P/E
               </th>
               <th>Sectoral Index
               </th>
               </tr>
               </thead>
       <tbody class="">
         <tr>
            <td>
               <div id="quoteEquitySeries" class="custom_select">
                   <select class="no-border-radius">
                       <option value="SM">SM
                       </option>
                   </select>
               </div>
             </td>
           <td>ZODIAC
           </td>
           <td>INE761Y01019
           </td>
           <td>Listed
           </td>
           <td>05-Dec-2017
           </td>
           <td>NA
           </td>
           <td>NA
           </td>
           <td>NA
           </td>
           <td>NA
           </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am new to BeautifulSoup. I Tried a bit but could not figure out how do I get the following dictionary?

```
{'Series': 'SM', 'Symbol': 'ZODIAC', 'ISIN': 'INE761Y01019', 'Status': 'Listed', 'Date of Listing': '05-Dec-2017', 'Industry': 'NA', 'Symbol P/E':'NA', 'Sectoral Index P/E': 'NA', 'Sectoral Index' : 'NA'}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the code you have already tried

Answer (score 1):

You can find the tag by it's id: `equityInfo`.

Here's how you can get the desired output using CSS selectors:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

headers = []
rows = []

for header in soup.select("#equityInfo thead th"):
    headers.append(header.get_text(separator="", strip=True))

for row in soup.select("#equityInfo tbody td"):
    rows.append(row.get_text(separator="", strip=True))


print(dict(zip(headers, rows)))
```

Output:

```
{'Series': 'SM', 'Symbol': 'ZODIAC', 'ISIN': 'INE761Y01019', 'Status': 'Listed', 'Date of Listing': '05-Dec-2017', 'Industry': 'NA', 'Symbol P/E': 'NA', 'Sectoral Index P/E': 'NA', 'Sectoral Index': 'NA'}
```

Documentation:

- [CSS selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)

Answer (score 1):

The data you need is present inside a `<table>` with `equityInfo` as it's `id`.

- Select the table with id=  `equityInfo`
- Get all the headers - `<th>` from the `<table>` and store them in a list - `ths`
- Get all the data -`<td>` from the `<table>` and store them in a list `rows`
- Since you need a `dict` as output, Use `zip` to zip the above two lists together and convert them to a `dict`

Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = '''
<div class="container">
   <div class="table-wrap table-onerow">
       <table id="equityInfo" class="eq-series table-fullwidth w-100">
          <thead>
             <tr>
               <th>Series
               </th>
               <th>Symbol
               </th>
               <th>ISIN
               </th>
               <th>Status
               </th>
               <th>Date of Listing
               </th>
               <th>Industry
               </th>
               <th>Symbol P/E
               </th>
               <th>Sectoral Index P/E
               </th>
               <th>Sectoral Index
               </th>
               </tr>
               </thead>
       <tbody class="">
         <tr>
            <td>
               <div id="quoteEquitySeries" class="custom_select">
                   <select class="no-border-radius">
                       <option value="SM">SM
                       </option>
                   </select>
               </div>
             </td>
           <td>ZODIAC
           </td>
           <td>INE761Y01019
           </td>
           <td>Listed
           </td>
           <td>05-Dec-2017
           </td>
           <td>NA
           </td>
           <td>NA
           </td>
           <td>NA
           </td>
           <td>NA
           </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
   </div>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', attrs= {'id': 'equityInfo'})
t = table.findAll('th')
ths = []
for i in t:
    ths.append(i.text.strip())

tds = table.findAll('td')
rows = []
for i in tds:
    rows.append(i.text.strip())

d = dict(zip(ths, rows))
print(d)
```

```
Output

{'Series': 'SM', 'Symbol': 'ZODIAC', 'ISIN': 'INE761Y01019', 'Status': 'Listed', 'Date of Listing': '05-Dec-2017', 'Industry': 'NA', 'Symbol P/E': 'NA', 'Sectoral Index P/E': 'NA', 'Sectoral Index': 'NA'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to find the xpaths of each desired element/value
Now use beautifulsoup to get the value
Add validations at this stage to avoid blanks
Save the obtained values in a list